# is there any way to keep sessions in memcache for long time

Tags: memcached

is there any way to keep sessions in memcache for long time just in case of login user for 1 month for example?

i mean after server restarted or crashes sessions wont disappear from memcache?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a unique string to a cookie on your users browser and make sure that string can match up to a record in your database corresponding to a user.  Then on every page load, check that cookie against the users table to see if there's a hit.  If so, that's your guy and he should be considered logged in and you can write whatever data you want, serverside, corresponding to that user.  You can set your cookie to never expire, which is what you want.

Sessions are a php thing, and php deals with where exactly the information is stored on the server.  You don't have control over what data storage type (mysql, memcached, etc) it uses.  It's stored in a directory somewhere which is abstracted away from you.  So, technically, the answer to your question is, no, you cannot store sessions in memcached, or any other type of data store for that matter.